# Verifying ID Token on jwt.io

Tags: keycloak

I am testing keycloak features for User Federation Kerberos/single sign on and Password Grant. When I paste the JWT ID token returned by keycloak in jwt.io, I get an error "Invalid Signature". I am capturing the JWT ID token from wireshark. The additional information in jwt.io is that the JWT signature is not encoded correctly using base64url. The algorithm is RS256. I have also copied the public key available in keycloak and pasted it in the JWT.io public key window. Any pointers to help resolve this?

{
"alg": "RS256",
"typ": "JWT",
"kid": "7XhgKPveGhbP7Dz0R6cca5z8AuFLqieslTFFInNw4-w"
}

Thanks,
S

Comment: From the top of my mind: JWT token has 3 parts; each part is encoded in Base64-URL-safe *without padding*; there's a separator char which is not a valid Base64 char and that's how you can spot it; parts 1 and 2 are JSON docs, part 3 is an ugly crypto binary thingy. If you have a specific issue with the encoding in part 3 I would bet it's an **extra character** -- e.g. a space or a Windows EOL char -- that `jwt.io` is too lame to strip automatically.

Comment: Thanks! Let me see if this is the issue.